# Contacts.app Sync with iCloud gives CoreDAVErrorDomain Error 1

Tags: icloud, contacts

I'm completely clueless.
The contacts app does not sync with iCould and gives the CoreDAVErrorDomain Error 1.

I have tried deleting the app and do software update. Same thing.
I have tried backing up contacts, delete all contacts, sync with iCloud. It downloads the data from iCloud and gives the error again. Not all contacts are updated.
I have tried backup contacts from iCloud, delete data from iCloud, delete data from the contacts app. When i load the backup contacts to iCloud it give this error again. Can my data be corrupted? It loads well to iCloud again and it was backed up from iCloud...

I have an iPhone that syncs perfectly to iCloud and would like the MAC contacts to be sync'd with the phone.

Please let me know if I am making this question in the wrong place.
I have also looked for an answer first, but could not find one.

[image: all the error information i have]

Comment: Did you find anything useful yet?

Comment: I never solved this. But i no longer use mac now :)